# Xamarin ios Missing App Store Icon warning

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've read every question on this over the past 2 weeks that I've been struggling with this. I want to update one of the apps I have in the store and I keep getting this message and I can't submit my update. [image]

I have set the new App store icon here

[image]

I have made sure it's 1024x1024, I have checked the color profile is sRGB and that there is no alpha in the image. The error you see was on my 14th attempt over 2 weeks and I don't know what to do anymore. I am using the latest stable release of Xcode as well.

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 7.3 (Switched to Preview after the stable didn't work) with Xamarin iOS Version: 11.4.0.93.

I would not be asking this question here unless I've tried everything I could think of. I wish this was a coding problem, those are much easier o solve than this arbitrary problem.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I too was facing this issue while uploading build  from latest Xcode. try taking your build from Xcode 8.(If you don't have any feature's depending on Xcode 9)

Comment: @jegadeesh I'm busy downloading it as we speak, an unstable 4mb line will make that take a while. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll report back if it worked.

Comment: Hope it works for you too!

Comment: have you add `iTunes Artwork` in `info.plist` file. In that file you have to add `512 * 512` and `1024 * 1024`.

Comment: Yes @Ironman you can't submit to the store without them and I already have a version of the app in the store so it's all there. Both are set.

Comment: @DaneMackier see my answer below. now you will get idea why this error occure,

Comment: @Ironman if you read my question you'll see that I have set that :)

Answer (score 1):

In xCode 9, they have added one additional app icon size with `1024px * 1024px` [image]

Go to `Assets.xcassets` and you can find this new addition at the bottom of your app icon image set.

Once you add app icon with 1024pt, it should fix the issue.

Comment: I know about that. I have set it as you can see in the image above, at this point I did that bout 9 times in total. I set it. Build my app, submit and get the same warning. 

Then I remove the image completely, delete the file, add everything back, build and submit and then get the warning. Then I did that another 7 times and it still didn't work

Comment: @DaneMackier in you `iTunesArtwork` you added `2x` can you add the same icon again. May be your icon size is not valid. you can try that.

Comment: I have both sizes, the correct sizes. 512x512 and 1024x1024. They both work fine and have been in the store that way for over a month now. The problem is the warning with the 1024 app store icon that's preventing me to submit an update.

Comment: I'm busy downloading xcode 8 and will perform the entire process using that since that's what I used for the first submission. I'll come back and let you know if it worked.

Comment: same build, no changes, when submitting with Xcode 8.3.3 it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

I tried every suggestion and nothing worked. Using the same build uploaded with the Application loader shipped with XCode 8.3.3 works.

**Edit**
The warning didn't show up when uploading through Application loader, but the app store still didn't accept it :( Same error when trying to submit for review.

**EDIT 2**
I had to build my app with target platform 8.2 and the error went away on submitting for review.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to add the icon in iTunes Connect. You only have to do it once. You will still get the warning ahen using Application Loader but it will be possible to submit the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, used https://makeappicon.com/ to generate the different image sizes the `idiom` in Contents.json is wrong (as of March 2020).

Either regenerate the `Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/` with Visual Studio by adding/removing images and saving or change `idiom` manually from `ios-marketing` to `ipad` (in my case) and it works.